# Select value in dropdown and use this value as condition in another dropdown

Tags: php, jquery

I want to select a value in a dropdown and use that value as the where condition for the query in another dropdown. 
I am saving the value in a cookie and it populates the correct information in the second dropdown list but when selecting another value, it does not load the data by the changed condition.

> Jquery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(function() {
    $('#Marca').change(function() { 
    var x = $(this).val();
    $("#myhidden").val(x); // Estou a passar o valor para um input text
    document.cookie = "x="+x;
    });
});
</script>
```

> PHP dropdown 1

```
   div class="form-group">
<label>Marca</label>
<?php

include('conetar.php');

$result = $conn->query("select * from marca");
echo "<select name='Marca' class='form-control'id='Marca' placeholder ='Introduza a Marca'>";
echo '<option value=""></option>';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($IDMarca, $Marca);
              $IDMarca = $row['IDMarca'];
              $Marca = $row['Marca']; 
              echo '<option value="'.$IDMarca.'">'.$Marca.'</option>';

}

echo "</select>";
$conn ->close();

?>
```

> PHP dropdown 2

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Modelo</label>

<?php
include('conetar.php');
// to send ajax data with commune   
$marca  =$_GET["marca"];

$query= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM modelo WHERE modelo.marca ='$marca'  ");


    echo "<select id='Modelo' name='Modelo' class='form-control' placeholder='Introduza o Modelo'>";
        echo '<option value=""></option>';
   while($getmodelo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

          unset($IDModelo, $Modelo);
          $IDModelo = $getmodelo['IDModelo'];
          $Modelo = $getmodelo['Modelo']; 
          echo '<option value="'.$IDModelo.'">'.$Modelo.'</option>';

}

echo "</select>";

mysqli_close($conn);

?> 
</div>
```

Comment: at jquery code : `document.cookie = "x="+x;`

Comment: Check what happens when you refresh the page. Did you see the same behavior?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, if i refresh the page, the `echo "$valor";  shows the last selected value

Comment: Well, that is the expected behavior. You have to use AJAX in this scenario. Can you show those two dropdown lists with which you're currently working?

Comment: I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated:

Use AJAX to send the `IDMarca` value of the selected brand to the backend PHP page. Subsequently, fetch the required data from `modelo` table using this `IDMarca` value and finally populate the second dropdown list in the `success` callback function of your AJAX request.

So your code should be like this:

The **first page** will have the first dropdown list, skeleton of second dropdown list(which you'll populate later using AJAX) and your jQuery/AJAX code.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Marca</label>
<?php
    include('conetar.php');

    $result = $conn->query("select * from Marca");
    echo "<select name='Marca' class='form-control' id='Marca' placeholder ='Introduza a Marca'>";
    echo '<option value=""></option>';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        unset($IDMarca, $Marca);
        $IDMarca = $row['IDMarca'];
        $Marca = $row['Marca']; 
        echo '<option value="'.$IDMarca.'">'.$Marca.'</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";
    $conn->close();
?> 


<div class="form-group">
    <label>Modelo</label>
    <select id='Modelo' name='Modelo' class='form-control' placeholder='Introduza o Modelo'>
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '#Marca', function(){
        var IDMarca = $(this).val();
        if(IDMarca.length){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'secondPage.php',
                cache: 'false',
                data: {IDMarca: IDMarca},
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#Modelo').html(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

***Don't forget*** to change `secondPage.php` in the `url` setting of your AJAX request.

The **second page** will process your AJAX request and fetch the required data, which will be used to populate the second dropdown list.

```
<?php
    include('conetar.php'); 
    if(isset($_POST['IDMarca'])){
        $IDMarca = $_POST['IDMarca'];
        $query= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM modelo WHERE modelo.marca ='$IDMarca'");
        while($getmodelo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            unset($IDModelo, $Modelo);
            $IDModelo = $getmodelo['IDModelo'];
            $Modelo = $getmodelo['Modelo']; 
            echo '<option value="'.$IDModelo.'">'.$Modelo.'</option>';
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

Comment: The question has been corrected. I put the same dropdown twice.

Comment: @djva Still the procedure would be same. Have you tried to incorporate the given changes(in my answer) to your code?

Comment: @djva You're welcome. Glad I could help.;-)  I've also updated my answer accordingly. Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). On the last note, please take care of the SQL query in the **second page**, the `WHERE` condition should be `... WHERE modelo.marcaid=='$IDMarca'");` i.e. put the *Marca id* column name instead of `marca` because it's the *brand id* you're sending through AJAX request.

Comment: I don't have  enough reputation to accept de answer but it resolved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is bad way to do it try some ajax calls  it gives you a better result 
try something like this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#Marca").on('change',function() {
    var x = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/yourquerycode.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: "marca="+x,
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {

            $("#modelo").html(response);

            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

});
});
```

modelo is your select input ,, then you can do the same thing for the next dropdown

your php code would be something like this

```
 <?php
include_once("include your configdb here");

// to send ajax data with commune   

if(isset($_GET["marca"]))  {

$marca  =strip_tags($_GET["marca"]);

$query= mysqli_query($db_conx,"select * from modelo where modelo.marca       ='$marca'  ");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
  { 


   while($getmodelo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

     $modelo = $getmodelo['modelo']; 
  ?>

<option value="<?php echo $modelo;?>"><?php echo $modelo;?></option>

<?php          

      }

   }   
  }
     ?>
```

i hope this works for you :)